# Do I need to play other games first?

Tags: resident-evil-orc

*Resident Evil: Operation Raccoon City* takes place during the events of *Resident Evil 2*. Having never played *Resident Evil 2*:

**Will I miss out on any significant story related points?**

Comment: I'm disappointed. I read the tag and was excited for a fantasy resident evil game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Racoon City is definitely the heart of the Resident Evil franchise and is first introduced in Resident Evil 2. I would be willing to bet that Operation Racoon City will have a fairly good "history lesson".

If you're worried though you can read the [Resident Evil 2 Wiki Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_Evil_2) or if you have a PS3, purchase a copy of Resident Evil 2 through the PlayStation Network.

Answer (score 3):

In Resident Evil: Operation Raccoon City, you play as soldiers who work for the Umbrella Corporation (named the Wolfpack), so you actually play on the opposite side as the protagonists of Resident Evil 2.  While Operation Raccoon City will provide you with some history of the outbreak and the events within Raccoon City, the game is still focused on the events of the city as they happen **to the Wolfpack**.

So if you're looking for a broad overview of the significant story points about what's going on in Raccoon City as a whole, Operation Raccoon City will provide that data while you're playing.  However, if what you're looking for is significant story points about what is happening to Leon and Claire as they try to survive in Resident Evil 2, you won't be exposed to much of that information in Operation Raccoon City because it has little relevance to what's happening to your characters in Operation Raccoon City.